# sql select from oracle in coldfusion

Tags: oracle, select, coldfusion

After a form submit, javascript function is called. JS checks to see if there is any data entered into the fields. On success, loads this CF page. The page is an ajax load, that is why I'm not using #form.value#.

The query is what is messing me up. I've run through the rest of the code multiple times, the only time there is an error is when the itemtitle line is added to the query:

```
<cfset fieldList = url.searchFields>
<cfset fieldArray = listToArray(fieldList)>
<!--- The fieldArray has the form field names and values in a one-dimensional array
so every odd index is a title and every even index is a value. Hence the step=2 ---
<cfloop index="testing" from="1" to=#ListLen(fieldList)# step="2">
    <cfif fieldArray[testing] is 'searchID'>
        <cfset itemid = fieldArray[testing + 1]>
        <cfoutput>itemid = #itemid#</cfoutput>
    </cfif>
    <cfif fieldArray[testing] is 'searchName'>
        <cfset itemtitle = fieldArray[testing + 1]>
        <cfoutput>itemtitle = #itemtitle#</cfoutput>
    </cfif>
    <cfoutput>#fieldArray[testing]# #fieldArray[testing + 1]#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>

    <cfquery name="searchItems" datasource="#thedb#">
        SELECT *
        FROM spp_items
        WHERE avail_mode LIKE '0' 
        <cfif isDefined('url.categoryID')> AND categoryid = #url.categoryID#</cfif>
        <cfif isDefined('itemid')> AND itemid = #itemid#</cfif>
<!--- if I comment this next line out, the query works fine --->
        <cfif isDefined('itemtitle')> AND itemtitle LIKE #itemtitle#</cfif>
    </cfquery>
```

Why is my query not working? Again, I have checked that the form submit, js function, and coldfusion syntax are all valid. Only when this line is added to the query does it break. Thanks.

Comment: Does the value of itemtitle contain single-quotes? Otherwise you'll get a syntax error from Oracle. Also, what error do you get? If you can't readily see, either use Fiddler to watch the AJAX call or of you only get a 500 error from CF, try adding checking the logs or inserting a < cfflush into the top of your code (it'll often force CF to send errors to output, rather than just displaying empty content)

Comment: You might also consider using cfqueryparam in this query, as it'll help sanitize input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code I can't see where you are adding quotes around the itemtitle value, it looks like you are currently executing a line which looks like:

```
AND itemtitle LIKE something
```

instead of:

```
AND itemtitle LIKE 'something'
```

Comment: Ahhh! I knew it was something dumb! I've spent hours with this... I'll accept your answer in a minute. Do you know why it is now only working when the form field matches exactly? Shouldn't 'like' match any matching characters, not just an entire word match?

Comment: Only if you give it the "%" wildcard character, so if you want to find string a anywhere in string b then you would need `LIKE '%something%'`